# List View(In UI) contains all the components not in the list view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

[image]I am trying to create a list view which would display records on entering a number. The number of records will be equal to the number entered in the given text field.
It is working fine but the problem is the list contains all the components of the UI which are not required in the list.

Below is my activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="poc.tusharimaging.com.bluetooth_poc.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="83dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/numOfRows"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/set"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/set" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Set"
            android:id="@+id/set"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/retrive"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/retrive" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/time"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/retrive"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/retrive" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Retrive"
                android:id="@+id/retrive"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/items"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/data"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The java code is as below.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> records;
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.items);
records = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main, R.id.data, values);
listView.setAdapter(records);
```

Comment: What do you mean by components of the UI which are not required in the list?

Comment: the components @+id/numOfRows, @+id/set, @+id/date,@+id/time and @+id/retrive are part of @+id/data along with data. attaching screen shot for details.

Comment: How are you attaching the layout to the ListView in the code @tushar?

Comment: Using array adapter.

Comment: You only want one TextView to show for each list item?

Comment: @speedDeveloper activity_main is my base layout. Are you saying that passing the base layout to the array adapter is causing the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106851/discussion-between-speeddeveloper-and-tushar).

Comment: @speedDeveloper yes I want only one TextView to show for each list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your ArrayAdapter like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> records;
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.items);
records = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item_layout, R.id.data, values);
listView.setAdapter(records);
```

because the ArrayAdapter takes an item layout to display the items in the ListView not the whole layout.
Docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

**list_item_layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TextView
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/data"
  ></TextView>
```

**base_layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="poc.tusharimaging.com.bluetooth_poc.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="83dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/numOfRows"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/set"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/set" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Set"
            android:id="@+id/set"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>



        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/retrive"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/retrive" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/time"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/retrive"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/retrive" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Retrive"
                android:id="@+id/retrive"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>



            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/items"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />





</LinearLayout>
```